# Server-side filtering with ng-grid: binding issue?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm posting this with reference to this **previous post** [Server-side paging+filtering+sorting for ng-grid with WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786091/server-side-pagingfilteringsorting-for-ng-grid-with-webapi), hoping to be able to finally come up with a simple, yet working sample of using ng-grid with external data sources. Up to this point, I've managed to implement external paging and sorting, but I'm facing an issue with filtering.

It *seems like the filterText property of ng-grid filter options is not bound to the view*. When I type something in the filter's text of the ng-grid my $watch-ed function does not get called, and thus I have no chance to request filtered data to the server. Yet, the same watch expressions work fine when used e.g. for paging or sorting.

By digging around a bit, I found this post https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/pull/456 about a bug right in this area, but it's not clear if this is still an open issue. Could anyone help?
Here is the relevant JS code snippet:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.filterOptions = {
        filterText: "",
        useExternalFilter: true
    };
    $scope.totalServerItems = 0;
    $scope.pagingOptions = {
        pageSizes: [25, 50, 100],
        pageSize: 25,
        currentPage: 1
    };
    $scope.sortOptions = {
        // omitted for brevity...
    };

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: "items",
        columnDefs: [
            { field: "id", displayName: "ID", width: "60" },
            { field: "name", displayName: "Name", pinnable: true },
            { field: "age", displayName: "Age", width: "60" },
            { field: "isFemale", displayName: "F", width: "40" }
        ],
        enablePaging: true,
        enablePinning: true,
        pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,        
        filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
        keepLastSelected: true,
        multiSelect: false,
        showColumnMenu: true,
        showFilter: true,
        showGroupPanel: true,
        showFooter: true,
        sortInfo: $scope.sortOptions,
        totalServerItems: "totalServerItems",
        useExternalSorting: true,
        i18n: "en"
    };

    $scope.refresh = function() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            // call the server and get data into $scope.items...
        }, 100);
    };

    // this WORKS    
    $scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
            $scope.refresh();
        }
    }, true);

    // this DOES NOT WORK: the function never gets called
    $scope.$watch('filterOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
            $scope.refresh();
        }
    }, true);

    // this WORKS
    $scope.$watch('sortOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
            $scope.refresh();
        }
    }, true);

    $scope.refresh();
}]);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't, because in the meantime other requirements led me to switch to another type of data presentation in my app. Yet, it would be nice to have a simple, working example for such scenarios requiring a grid.

Answer (score 5):

This might be bit late but its better late than never :)

I had success by directly binding to the filterText property of gridOptions like below

```
$scope.$watch('gridOptions.$gridScope.filterText', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        }
}, true);
```

Comment: Thanks bro, this work on me. `$gridScope` is the key @_@