# Ng-grid with external data and TypeScript: compile error "Cannot set property 'gridDim' of undefined"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ng-grid

Update #1: after the fix I commented about, now my app starts but *the grid is not rendered* except for its bounding box and filter button and popup. Yet, I get no error from the console, and as far as I can arrive with the debugger, I can see that data got from the server are OK. If I use Batarang, I can see the scope corresponding to my model, correctly filled with items. I updated the downloadable repro solution accordingly. Could anyone explain why ng-grid is not updating here?

---

I'm starting to play with ng-grid and TypeScript and I'm finding issues as soon as my test app starts up. See the bottom of this post for a link to a full test solution. Surely I have made tons of errors even in these few files, but I'd like to have something to start with and learn more step by step.

The MVC app has two client-side applications:

- app.js for the default view (Home/Index). No typescript here, and the whole code is self-contained in this single file. The code is derived from the paging example in the ng-grid documentation and tries to stay as simplest as possible.
- MyApp.js for the more realistic sample in another view (Home/Model). This sample uses services, models and controllers and its JS code is compiled from TypeScript. To keep things simple, I'm just storing these components under Scripts/App, in folders for Controllers, Models and Services, and each file contains just a single class or interface. The generated JS files are manually included in the view.

app.js works, except that it has issues with filtering. I posted about these here:
[Server-side filtering with ng-grid: binding issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862318/server-side-filtering-with-ng-grid-binding-issue)

MyApp.js has startup issues with ng-grid. As soon as the app starts, a TypeError is thrown in the grid binding:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'gridDim' of undefined
    at ngGridDirectives.directive.ngGridDirective.compile.pre (http://localhost:55203/Scripts/ng-grid-2.0.7.js:2708:37)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:55203/Scripts/angular.js:4392:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:55203/Scripts/angular.js:4015:15)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:55203/Scripts/angular.js:4400:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:55203/Scripts/angular.js:4015:15)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:55203/Scripts/angular.js:3920:30)
    at resumeBootstrapInternal (http://localhost:55203/Scripts/angular.js:983:27)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:55203/Scripts/angular.js:8057:28)
    at Object.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:55203/Scripts/angular.js:8137:23)
    at resumeBootstrapInternal (http://localhost:55203/Scripts/angular.js:981:15) <div ng-grid="gridOptions" style="height: 400px" class="ng-scope"> angular.js:5754
```

The only similar issue I found by googling is https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/60, but it does not seem to be related to my case as there the grid options were setup too late.

The server side just has an API RESTful controller returning server-paged, sorted and filtered items.

You can find the full repro solution here (just save, unzip and open; all the dependencies come from NuGet); see the readme.txt file for more information:

http://sdrv.ms/167gv0F

Just start the app and click MODEL in the upper right corner to run the TypeScript app throwing the error. The whole app is composed of 1 controller, 1 service and 1 model.

For starters like me, it would be nice to have a simple working example like this one. Could anyone help?

Comment: By stepping into the ng-grid source I found a first issue, really a typo: the view requires a div for the grid with attribute ng-grid="shell.gridOptions". I forgot the shell. property name in pasting.

Comment: For others using Typescript the correct way to use a controller is to set the class instance as a view model on the scope: `this.$scope.vm = this` and then for ng-grid: `this.gridData = []; this.gridOptions = { data: "vm.gridData" }` . For some reason the prop must be access via string like this and you cannot do `data: this.gridData`

Comment: @parliament that some reasonable, tried it out but no go :(

Answer (score 6):

This error means `gridOptions` has not yet been defined by the time that Angular attempts to parse `ng-grid="yourArray"`, where `yourArray` is the same array supplied to `gridOptions`. I had the same problem after refactoring a previously working `ng-grid`.

So `gridOptions` must be defined *before* the element which has `ng-grid="yourArray"` attribute applied to it (rather than within that element's own controller).

I resolved this by defining `gridOptions` in an outer element somewhere (on global/app scope, for instance).

P.S. Maybe there is a better way, but this has worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me. ng-grid and ng-controller cannot be on the same element

Comment: +1  @NickWiggill any chance of a small code example? I.E "gridOptions must be defined before the element which has ng-grid="yourArray" attribute applied to it (rather than within that element's own controller)" - where, than

Comment: @parliament +1 same question -any small code example, or even just a description of how/where? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Where you are adding data to your grid?

If you are writing **$scope.myGrid={data:"someObj"};** in a success call then it won't work.

See the below reason:(which is listed in https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/60)

```
You can't define the grid options in the success call. You need to define
them on the scope in your controller and then set the data or column
definitions, etc... from the success call.
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not seem to be the problem. My grid options are set in a model, which is added to the scope in my controller's constructor. On success, the data items array of this model is populated. You can find more in the repro solution quoted in my first post.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do?, First is to see how this made ​​your project and revizar if your queries or data access, the beams through a service, if so this I must add the file that manages routes app, the client side.

remain so.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('iseApp', [
        'ngCookies',
        'ngResource',
        'ngSanitize',
        'ngRoute',
        **'ngGrid',**
        'campaignServices',
        'dialinglistServices',
        'itemServices'
    ])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $routeProvider
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are adding your ng-grid in a directive, you have to make sure the grid options are loaded before it tries to parse your html.

You could set a boolean in your link function :

```
scope.isDirectiveLoaded=true;
```

And then, in your template, use a ng-if :

```
<div ng-if="isDirectiveLoaded">
    <div ng-grid="myGrid"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got to the same issue, empty grid was rendered. 
The way I got to it in the end was to setup my this.gridOptions in the constructor of the controller, within the component.  In the options everything is referenced with $ctrl like this.  So the data references $ctrl.gridData. gridData is specified as a property in my component controller. $ctrl is not defined as a property.
This was done in the constructor before the data was loaded. this.gridData was defined after in the constructor and then populated later in another function. The options were defined first, I think this is important from some things I read.

For the event hooks pass null instead of $scope.

```
this.gridOptions = {
    enableGridMenu: true,
    minRowsToShow: 25,
    rowHeight: 36,
    enableRowHashing: true,
    data: '$ctrl.gridData',
    rowTemplate: this.$rootScope.blockedRowTemplate,
    onRegisterApi: ($ctrl) => {
        this.gridApi = $ctrl;
        this.gridApi.colMovable.on.columnPositionChanged(null, (colDef, originalPosition, newPosition) => {
            this.saveState();
        });

        this.gridApi.colResizable.on.columnSizeChanged(null, (colDef, deltaChange) => {
            this.saveState();
        });

        this.gridApi.core.on.columnVisibilityChanged(null, (column) => {
            this.saveState();
        });

        this.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged(null, (grid, sortColumns) => {
            this.saveState();
        });
        this.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged(null, (grid, sortColumns) => {
            this.saveState();
        });
    }
};
```

In the row template I was referencing functions defined in my component. Before conversion to a component I referenced functions like this:

```
ng-click="grid.appScope.jumpToExport(row.entity);"
```

After conversion to the component I needed to add the $ctrl before the function name like this

```
ng-click="grid.appScope.$ctrl.jumpToExport(row.entity);"
```

And this is how the component is referenced in the html

```
<div ui-grid="$ctrl.gridOptions" ng-if="$ctrl.gridData.length != undefined && $ctrl.gridData.length > 0" class="data-grid" ui-grid-save-state ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-move-columns></div>
```